# Using of LIKE or CONCAT while seaching by middle of string in MySql will be more effective?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I am often searching by the middle of strings like 'pre-var-post'.
In such cases, sometimes I write queries with condition like this:

`dirDeptGroup = CONCAT('pre-', ?, '-post')`

sometimes like this

`dirDeptGroup like 'pre-?-post')`

But how will it be more efficient for MySql? Intuitively, it seems to me that comparison using the equal sign is faster and easier than using like. What do you think?

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: Direct compare is more fast then pattern check, even when the pattern does not contain wildcards.

Comment: How to test? Results are unstable in time.

Comment: Ok. I tryed to test.

Answer (score 0):

Both conditions do not do the same thing.

> `dirDeptGroup = CONCAT('pre-', ?, '-post')`

This seems to do what you want, that is concatenate the parameter with the literal strings, and perform an equality check.

> `dirDeptGroup like 'pre-?-post'`

The parameter is buried in a string: it is not a parameter any more, but a literal string: exactly `'pre-?-post'`. That's probably not what you want. Another thing to note is that the string has no wildcard anyway (`'_'` or `'%'`), so the `like` condition is functionally equivalent to an equality check.

There is no value added by using `like` here, and I would suspect that it will degrade efficiency - unless MySQL is smart enough to identify the lack of wildcard, and optimize the operation to an equality check.